# C++ struct directly followed by parentheses to form a functor?

Tags: c++

When I read std::function, I find the following syntax confusing. What does a struct followed directly by empty parentheses do here? It works equivalent to declare a struct object instead and call its operator.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    struct F {
        bool operator()(int a) {
            return a>0;
        }
    };

    function<bool(int)> f = F(); //What does the syntax F() mean here?
    struct F ff;
    cout <<  f(1) <<endl; 
    cout << ff(1) <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It simply constructs an instance of the `F` type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Functors - and their uses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses)

Comment: @JonHarper Not really. This isn't asking about calling `operator()` on an object, it's asking about constructing one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does the syntax F() mean here?

It means construct an object of type `F` using the default constructor.

A `std::function` can be constructed using any callable object that meets its calling criteria. In your particular use case, an instance of `F` meets those criteria for `std::function<bool(int)>`. Hence,

```
function<bool(int)> f = F();
```

is a valid statement to construct `f`.

Comment: Thanks. This helps. The last still puzzling to me is what is the F() doing here? I presume it returns something like `new F()`?

Comment: @lkahtz It simply returns an object instance of type `F` where as `new F()` would return **a pointer** to an object instance of type `F`.

Comment: @lkahtz, to add to the comment James Adkison, `new F()` will allocate memory for an object from the heap, construct an object of type `F` using that memory, and then return a pointer to that object.

Comment: Thanks James, Tobi and R Sahu

Answer (score 2):

Dont get confused by the fact that calling the default constuctor also uses `()`. This

```
function<bool(int)> f = F();
```

calls the constructor and assigns the object to the function `f`, while this

```
f(1)
```

calls the `operator()`.

Comment: Thanks. So `F()` is actually calling the constructor here. It still confuses me that a struct constructor is called without `new`. And why is a template class instance `f` declared and assigned here, by the returned value of a struct constructor?

Comment: @lkahtz See the first answer provided by @RSahu for the details of `f`.

Comment: @lkahtz dont use `new` to construct objects if you dont need to. Objects are simply constructed by calling the constructor (hence its name ;).